# Breaking frames in beamer with equations

Tags: beamer, equations, allowframebreaks

I have the MWE in the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1] %to allow automatic page breaks for formulas written with \alignat


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Mathematical model}

 \textbf{Modelo matemático:}


\begin{alignat}{2}
 \mbox{maximize  } z_1  =  & \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{k \in V} \left( p_{ki} + q_i \right)~y_{ki}    \label{Obj1} \\
  \hspace{-0.5cm}\mbox{minimize  } z_2  = &  \sum_{(i,j) \in A} c_{ij}~x_{ij}    \label{Obj2} \\
 \mbox{subject to} &
                   && \nonumber \\
& \sum_{j:(1,j) \in A} x_{1j} = 1, &&  j \in V    \label{Restricao1} \\
& \sum_{i:(i,1) \in A} x_{i1} = 1, &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao2} \\
& \sum_{j \in V} x_{ij} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} = 0, \qquad &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao3} \\
& \sum_{i \in V} x_{ij} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{kj} = 0, &&  j \in V    \label{Restricao4} \\
& x_{ij} - y_{1j} = 0, &&  j \in V    \label{Restricao5} \\
& x_{ij} +1 \geq y_{ki} + y_{(k+1)j},  &&  (i,j) \in A, \quad k \in V    \label{Restricao6} \\
& w_j \geq w_0 + e_{1j} \cdot x_{1j} - M \cdot (1-x_{1j}) &&  (1,j) \in A    \label{Restricao7} \\
& w_j \geq w_i + \left( e_{ij} + d_i \right)\cdot x_{ij} - M \cdot (1-x_{ij}) \quad \quad && (i,j) \in A, \quad i \neq 1    \label{Restricao8} \\
& \sum_{t \in T} \phi_{it} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} = 0 &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao9} \\
& z_{it} \leq M \cdot \phi_{it}  &&  i \in V, \quad t \in T    \label{Restricao10} \\
& w_i - \sum_{t \in T} z_{it} = 0 &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao11} \\
& a_{it} \cdot \phi_{it} \leq z_{it} \leq b_{it} \cdot \phi_{it}  &&  i \in V, \quad t \in T    \label{Restricao12}\\
& \alpha_t \leq \sum_{i \in B} \phi_{it} \leq \beta_t &&  t \in T    \label{Restricao13}\\
& \sum_{i \in R_t} \phi_{it} =1 &&  t \in T    \label{Restricao14}\\
& \sum_{i \in H_t} \phi_{it} =1  &&  t \in T\setminus{|T|}    \label{Restricao15}\\
&  \sum_{i \in V} y_{ki} \geq \sum_{i \in V} y_{(k+1)i}  && k \in V\setminus \{n\}      \label{Restricao16}\\
&  \sum_{i \in V} y_{ki} \leq 1  && k \in V     \label{Restricao17}\\
&  \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki}  \leq 1  &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao18}\\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} && (i,j) \in A     \label{Restricao19}\\
& y_{ki} \in \{0,1\} && i \in V, \quad k \in V     \label{Restricao20}\\
& \phi_{it} \in \{0,1\} &&  i \in V, \quad t \in T   \label{Restricao21}\\
& w_{i} \geq 0 && i \in V     \label{Restricao22}\\
& z_{it} \geq 0 && i \in V, \quad t \in T.     \label{Restricao23}
\end{alignat}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

whose ressult is undesired:

[image]

I would like to break my mathematical model (inside the environment `alignat`) in two or more frames. I tried use `allowframebreaks` as option but not work.
Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't rely on automatic frame breaking. I further suggest that you place the 23 restrictions in two-column `column` environments. This will let you typeset all 25 equations in just two frames.

[image]

Aside: Are you sure it's a good idea to inflict all 25 equations on the audience of your talk? Which of these equations (if any!) do you think they'll remember longer than about five minutes after the conclusion of your talk?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,array,xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Modelo matemático I}
\begin{align}
\max z_1  &= \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{k \in V} ( p_{ki} + q_i )\,y_{ki}  \label{Obj1} \\
\min z_2  &= \sum_{\mathclap{(i,j) \in A}} c_{ij}\,x_{ij}            \label{Obj2} 
\end{align}

subject to
\small
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
&\sum_{\mathclap{j:(1,j) \in A}} x_{1j} = 1, \quad j\in V          \label{Restricao1} \\
&\sum_{\mathclap{i:(i,1) \in A}} x_{i1} = 1, \quad i\in V          \label{Restricao2} \\
& \sum_{j \in V} x_{ij} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} = 0, \quad i \in V \label{Restricao3}
\end{align}

\column{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i \in V} x_{ij} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{kj} = 0, \quad j \in V \label{Restricao4} \\[\jot]
& x_{ij} - y_{1j} = 0, \quad   j \in V                             \label{Restricao5} \\[3\jot]
& x_{ij} +1 \geq y_{ki} + y_{(k+1)j},                              \label{Restricao6} \\
&\qquad  (i,j) \in A, \ k \in V   \notag  
\end{align}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Modelo matemático II}
\small
\begin{columns}
\column{0.52\textwidth}
\begin{align}
& w_j \geq w_0 + e_{1j}  x_{1j} - M  (1-x_{1j}),        \label{Restricao7} \\
& \qquad (1,j) \in A  \notag\\
& w_j \geq w_i + ( e_{ij} + d_i ) x_{ij}                \label{Restricao8} \\
& \qquad  - M  (1-x_{ij}) (i,j), 
  \quad i\in A, \ i \neq 1 \notag\\
& \sum_{t \in T} \phi_{it} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} = 0, 
  \quad   i \in V                                       \label{Restricao9}  \\
& z_{it} \leq M  \phi_{it},  \quad   i \in V, \ t \in T \label{Restricao10} \\
& w_i - \sum_{t \in T} z_{it} = 0, \quad   i \in V      \label{Restricao11} \\
& a_{it}  \phi_{it} \leq z_{it} \leq b_{it}  \phi_{it}, 
  \quad   i \in V, \ t \in T                            \label{Restricao12} \\
& \alpha_t \leq \sum_{i \in B} \phi_{it} \leq \beta_t,
  \quad   t \in T                                       \label{Restricao13} \\
& \sum_{i \in R_t} \phi_{it} =1, \quad   t \in T        \label{Restricao14}
\end{align}

\column{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i \in H_t} \phi_{it} =1, \quad t\in T\setminus{|T|}   \label{Restricao15}\\
& \sum_{i \in V} y_{ki} \geq \sum_{i \in V} y_{(k+1)i},
  \ k \in V \setminus \{n\}                                   \label{Restricao16}\\
& \sum_{i \in V} y_{ki} \leq 1,  \quad k \in V                \label{Restricao17}\\
& \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} \leq 1,  \quad i \in V                \label{Restricao18}\\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, \quad  (i,j) \in A                      \label{Restricao19}\\
& y_{ki} \in \{0,1\}, \quad  i \in V, \ k \in V               \label{Restricao20}\\
& \phi_{it} \in \{0,1\}, \quad   i \in V, \ t \in T           \label{Restricao21}\\
& w_{i} \geq 0, \quad  i \in V                                \label{Restricao22}\\
& z_{it} \geq 0, \quad  i \in V, \ t \in T.                   \label{Restricao23}
\end{align}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the answer by @Mico, you'll get a much nicer result with manually constructed out frames.

---

Just for completeness: you could theoretically use the `allowdisplaybreaks` option to allow pagebreaks within the math contents:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1] %to allow automatic page breaks for formulas written with \alignat


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,allowdisplaybreaks]{Mathematical model}

 \textbf{Modelo matemático:}


\begin{alignat}{2}
 \mbox{maximize  } z_1  =  & \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{k \in V} \left( p_{ki} + q_i \right)~y_{ki}    \label{Obj1} \\
  \hspace{-0.5cm}\mbox{minimize  } z_2  = &  \sum_{(i,j) \in A} c_{ij}~x_{ij}    \label{Obj2} \\
 \mbox{subject to} &
                   && \nonumber \\
& \sum_{j:(1,j) \in A} x_{1j} = 1, &&  j \in V    \label{Restricao1} \\
& \sum_{i:(i,1) \in A} x_{i1} = 1, &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao2} \\
& \sum_{j \in V} x_{ij} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} = 0, \qquad &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao3} \\
& \sum_{i \in V} x_{ij} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{kj} = 0, &&  j \in V    \label{Restricao4} \\
& x_{ij} - y_{1j} = 0, &&  j \in V    \label{Restricao5} \\
& x_{ij} +1 \geq y_{ki} + y_{(k+1)j},  &&  (i,j) \in A, \quad k \in V    \label{Restricao6} \\
& w_j \geq w_0 + e_{1j} \cdot x_{1j} - M \cdot (1-x_{1j}) &&  (1,j) \in A    \label{Restricao7} \\
& w_j \geq w_i + \left( e_{ij} + d_i \right)\cdot x_{ij} - M \cdot (1-x_{ij}) \quad \quad && (i,j) \in A, \quad i \neq 1    \label{Restricao8} \\
& \sum_{t \in T} \phi_{it} - \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki} = 0 &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao9} \\
& z_{it} \leq M \cdot \phi_{it}  &&  i \in V, \quad t \in T    \label{Restricao10} \\
& w_i - \sum_{t \in T} z_{it} = 0 &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao11} \\
& a_{it} \cdot \phi_{it} \leq z_{it} \leq b_{it} \cdot \phi_{it}  &&  i \in V, \quad t \in T    \label{Restricao12}\\
& \alpha_t \leq \sum_{i \in B} \phi_{it} \leq \beta_t &&  t \in T    \label{Restricao13}\\
& \sum_{i \in R_t} \phi_{it} =1 &&  t \in T    \label{Restricao14}\\
& \sum_{i \in H_t} \phi_{it} =1  &&  t \in T\setminus{|T|}    \label{Restricao15}\\
&  \sum_{i \in V} y_{ki} \geq \sum_{i \in V} y_{(k+1)i}  && k \in V\setminus \{n\}      \label{Restricao16}\\
&  \sum_{i \in V} y_{ki} \leq 1  && k \in V     \label{Restricao17}\\
&  \sum_{k \in V} y_{ki}  \leq 1  &&  i \in V    \label{Restricao18}\\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} && (i,j) \in A     \label{Restricao19}\\
& y_{ki} \in \{0,1\} && i \in V, \quad k \in V     \label{Restricao20}\\
& \phi_{it} \in \{0,1\} &&  i \in V, \quad t \in T   \label{Restricao21}\\
& w_{i} \geq 0 && i \in V     \label{Restricao22}\\
& z_{it} \geq 0 && i \in V, \quad t \in T.     \label{Restricao23}
\end{alignat}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]